# Re-color a background of a scanned image with ImageMagic

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I have an image, coming out of a scan, that I would like to reproduce it in several different colors against multiple different colored backgrounds, like the one bellow:

[image]

I can easily change the color of the bug with level-color conversion, as in:

```
convert image.png +level-colors red, red-image.png
```

and produce an stupendously good quality image:

[image]

I understand (from many postings here) that making the background color transparent in a scan is one of the most difficult operations on an image. My question is:

Is there a way to change the background color -- by level -- in a similar way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **ImageMagick**, you can recolor the background using `-fill ... -opaque`. Measure the color of the background, then

```
convert insect.png -fuzz 5% -fill skyblue -opaque "rgb(235,215,186)" insect_blue.png
```

[image]

The `-fuzz X%` permits coloring of close but not exactly the measured color. This allows non-uniform background color to be changed. The larger the `X%`, the more it will color parts of the image.

A value of `0%` means only color the exact value measured.

See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#opaque

Comment: Fred, can one make it background-transparent using a similar trick?

Comment: Yes, use `-channel rgba -fill none` So for this image. `convert insect.png -fuzz 5% -channel rgba -fill none -opaque "rgb(235,215,186)" insect_trans.png` You can also use `-fill transparent` in place of `-fill none`